# Finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & D^{(2)} \\ D^{(N-2)} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, block-matrices

Recently encountered the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0^{2 \times (N-2)} & D^{2 \times 2} \\ D^{(N-2) \times (N-2)} & 0^{(N-2) \times 2} \end{pmatrix}$$

where $0^{(k \times l)}$ is the matrix of all zeros of the corresponding size, and $D^{(k \times l)}$ is diagonal. So, it consists only of two non-trivial diagonal blocks, however, they are not on the diagonal. Is there any simple way to diagonalize that?

What I also know is that $A^{m}$ is diagonal, where $m=N$ if $N$ is odd, and $m=N/2$ if $N$ is even. I believe that there is an analytical formula for that as I ran some symbolic tests.

Comment: You are looking for a way to do this that is not using the eigenvalue/vector procedure? How are you arriving at that matrix form? What basis are you choosing?

Comment: Since no one has answered your question yet, there is no reason to append an update. Why not just refine your question? If Kevin's comment is orphaned, so be it.

Comment: Your notation is problematic. You use $D$ to denote two different matrices.

Comment: Are all the entries on the main diagonals of the diagonal blocks the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $A$ is complex and nonsingular. If so, it is always diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. Let all matrices below be **zero-indexed**. Let
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ 1&&&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $A$ is in the form of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf a)\,C^{N-2}$ for some vector $\mathbf a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{N-1})^\top\in\mathbb C^N$.

When $N$ is odd, let $J$ be the index vector $(0,N-2,N-4,\ldots,1,N-1,N-3,\ldots,2)$ and $P=I(\,:\,,J)$ be the permutation matrix such that $p_{i,K(i)}=1$ for each $i$ and $p_{ij}=0$ elsewhere. Let also $\mathbf b=\mathbf a(J)=P^\top\mathbf a$. Then
$$
P^TAP=A(J,J)=\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b)C.\tag{1}
$$
When $N=2m$ is even, let $J_1=(0,N-2,N-4,\ldots,2),\,J_2=(1,N-1,N-3,\ldots,3)$ and $J=(J_1,J_2)$ be the concatenation of $J_1$ and $J_2$. Let $P=I(\,:\,,J),\,\mathbf b_1=\mathbf a(J_1),\,\mathbf b_2=\mathbf a(J_2)$ and $\mathbf b=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf b_1\\ \mathbf b_2\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf a(J)=P^\top\mathbf a$. Then
$$
P^TAP=A(J,J)
=\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b_1)C\\
&\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b_2)C
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So, in either case, the problem reduces to finding an eigen-decomposition of a nonsingular matrix in the form of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b)C$. Let $k$ be any $N$-th root of $b_0b_1\cdots b_{N-1}$. Define $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_0,d_1,\ldots,d_{N-1})$ where
$$
d_i=\frac{b_ib_{i+1}\cdots b_{N-1}}{k^{N-i}};\quad 0\le i<N.
$$
Then $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b)C=kDCD^{-1}$. However, it is well-known that the circulant matrix $C$ has a [unitary diagonalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $U\Lambda U^\ast$ where
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda&=\operatorname{diag}(1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{N-1}),\\
u_{ij}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\omega^{ij} \text{ for each $i,j\in\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$},\\
\omega&=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\mathbf i}{N}\right) \text{ (with $\mathbf i=\sqrt{-1}$)}.
\end{aligned}
It follows that $(DU)(k\Lambda)(DU)^{-1}$ is an eigen-decomposition of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b)C=kDCD^{-1}$.

So, when $N$ is odd, $A=(PDU)(k\Lambda)(PDU)^{-1}$ is an eigen-decomposition.

When $N$ is even, if $(D_1U)(k_1\Lambda)(D_1U)^{-1}$ and $(D_2U)(k_2\Lambda)(D_2U)^{-1}$ are respectively eigen-decompositions of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b_1)C$ and $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf b_2)C$, then
$$
\left(P\begin{bmatrix}D_1U\\ &D_2U\end{bmatrix}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}k_1\Lambda_1\\ &k_2\Lambda_2\end{bmatrix}
\left(P\begin{bmatrix}D_1U\\ &D_2U\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
$$
is an eigen-decomposition of $A$.